# Can a Go program start 8k+ Goroutines simultaneously?

Tags: go

I need to start multiple goroutines for sending http requests. The following is my code:

```
func InteractWithCheck(clusterId int, tableName string, key string, jobs <-chan int, results chan<- objRes) error {
    // the host only test
    host := "http://xxx.yyy.com/a/b?method=check&"
    for _ = range jobs {
        url := fmt.Sprintf("%scluster=%d&table=%s&key=%s", host, clusterId, tableName, key)
        for intRetry := 0; intRetry < 3; intRetry++ {
            resp, err := http.Get(url)
            if err != nil {
                continue
            }
            if resp.StatusCode >= 500 {
                continue
            }
            defer resp.Body.Close()
            body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            // ...
            return nil
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

`DataCheck` will call `InteractWithCheck` with `go`, the following code:

```
func DataCheck(clusterId int, tableName string, keyList []string) error {
    // ...

    for _, sliceKey := range keyList {
        // when len(keyList) > 8000, it will be hang
        go InteractWithCheck(clusterId, tableName, sliceKey, jobs, results)
    }

    for j := 0; j < num; j++ {
        jobs <- j
    }
    close(jobs)

    for k := 0; k < num; k++ {
        select {
        case res := <-results:
            // check result
            // ...
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

When `len(keylist) >= 8000`, the program will be hang, so I should optimize it?

Comment: Yes, you can start as many goroutines as you want within the limits of memory. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: It's hard to tell from the code, since you've cut out some rather important parts (like where various variables are declared, and what they are initialized to), but I'd wager you're running into an issue with channel deadlocking, not goroutines themselves.  How you're managing the `jobs` channel and sending to the `results` channel and reading from it is extremely suspect and doesn't seem like it would be doing anything actually useful.  I'd look at what you're actually trying to do, and maybe add logging to figure out where it's hanging.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of available goroutines to spawn depends on your RAM, live memory of your computer. So yes, you can start 8k+, but not if your computer can't handle it.